# Calendar (Timeline) widget for showing events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calendar

I have got some events: some of them are continuous, some of them are just one-day-events.

I want to beautifully show them on a web page. There is a bunch of date pickers jQuery plugins but I can't find any for showing events.

It can be something with canvas, or svg, or css. I don't need extra functionality. I need just to visualize my data and colorize some events. Something like just a line with date marks and colored event lines on it. Some kind of TIMELINE, yes

Comment: Fullcalendar? http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Comment: @Calum, not exactly. I need something simplier only to vizualize my data.

Comment: Let me get this.. you want to _visualize_ your date based event data - which you referenced with a date-picker, and you don't mean it to be a calendar?

Comment: @dakdad, Now it is just a list (date based event data), that I want to show as a timeline (not a calendar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the Simile widget, **[Timeline](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/)**?

Comment: Looks pretty good. Not exactly I want. But something I can use if there is no alternative. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

To add a few options, I'm just going to give you three more:

- [chap-links-library example](http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/timeline/examples/example15_mobile.html) and its [github repository](https://github.com/almende/chap-links-library)
- [TimelineJS](http://timeline.verite.co/)
- [Chronoline](http://stoicloofah.github.io/chronoline.js/)

All of them have different applications!